# How can I use different model for Auth component in CakePHP 2.0.4?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

It looks like trivial thing, but I really can't find where I can change it.
I want to use my "Player" model instead of User, but every time I go on /players/login it redirects me to "Missing Controller" page and link changes to /users/login.

I tried:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array('all' => array('userModel' => 'Player'))
     )
);
```

and

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('all' => array('userModel' => 'Player'));
}
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**

```
'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'login')
```

in $components array helped, I think :D

Comment: Does your PlayersController exists? Where are you putting this code?

Comment: @Entropy of course my PlayersController exist, and I am putting this in AppController. I am also doing parent::beforeFilter() in PlayersController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you aren't providing an authenticating system. You're providing some settings to be used in all the authenticating system that will be chosen, but you haven't chosen one yet (you have to provide at least one like Form, Basic, Digest, ecc..).

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'all' => array('userModel' => 'Member'),
    'Form',
    'Basic'
);
```

(or the same in the `$components` array)

Comment: I don't understand what are those for. If I am using forms to login i should add Form?

Comment: Well, you have to identify your users in some way, otherwise how would CakePHP know if they're logged in or not?
Maybe try to have a read of this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html.

Comment: Yes exactly, you should add ‘Form’ if you use a form to login, and then set your login action as explained in the page!

Comment: oh you mean loginAction array ?

Comment: I meant your actual action in your PlayerController. You should specify in action called login as in this paragraph: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in, in which you take the data from the login form and authenticate the user. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7033/discussion-between-maxorq-and-entropy)

Answer (score 0):

**You should do so**

```
public $components=array(
    'Session',
    'Auth'=>array(
        'authenticate'=>array(
            'Form'=>array(
                'userModel'=>'Player',
             )
        ),
        'loginAction'=>array('controller'=>'Players', 'action'=>'login'),
```

Comment: It may help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Use this code within controller :

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'applications',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),

    'logoutRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'applications',
        'action' => 'login'
    ),

    'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
                'userModel' => 'Application'
            )
        ),      
    )
);
```

Do not needed to add any code for beforeFilter() function. $components load the Auth conponent.

Thanks
Sujay