# CakePHP 2.1 Auth->login() not working, but adding user does

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I've searched through many posts on stackoverflow for an answer, and prehaps I'm just overlooking something, but I can't seem to get $this->Auth->login() to work. I've tried many different suggestions from other posts. I will try to be as thorough as possible when describing other methods I've tried.

I do have adding a user working. The MD5 hashing is working correctly. I hashed a password and then checked it using miracle salad md5 http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php

I do not use a salt for hashing. I use MD5 without a salt.

The database I'm using is Postgresql 9.0. I know some of the CakePhp magic doesn't work for all databases (or so I've been told).

#### **app/Config/core.php**

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');

/**
* A random string used in security hashing methods.
*/

    Configure::write('Security.salt', '');
```

I was using Auth->fields to map password to user_password and username to user_name in the DB. user_password and user_name are the columns in the core_users table. I also had in the beforeFilter() method.

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'user_password');
```

#### **app/Controller/AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
        'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'CoreUsers', 'action' => 'login'),
        /*'fields' => array('password' => 'user_password', 'username' => 'user_name'),*/
        'userModel' => 'CoreUser'
    )
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    Security::setHash('md5');
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
    //debug($this->Auth);
} 
}
```

I left the debugs in so you can see the order that they are processed and I will show you how they are printed.

#### **app/Controller/CoreUsersController.php**

```
    public function login() {
    Security::setHash('md5');
    //debug($this->Auth);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug(Security::hash($this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['user_password']));
        debug($this->Auth);
        debug(Configure::version());
        debug($this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['user_password']);
        debug($this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['user_name']);
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            debug($this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['user_password']);
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());

        } else {
            debug($this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['user_password']);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

#### **app/Model/CoreUser.php**

```
 App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class CoreUser extends AppModel{
public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public $sequence = 'core_user_id_seq';
public $name = 'CoreUser';
public $validate = array(
    'user_name' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'User name is required'
        )
    ),
    'user_password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Password is required'
        )
    ),
    'privilege_id' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Privilege ID is required'
        ),
        'legalValues' => array(
             'rule' => array('between',1,4),
            'message' => 'Privilege must be between 1 and 4'
        )
    ),
    'user_initial' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'User initials is required'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => array('email',true),
        'message' => 'Email must have an \'@\' symbol and a domain e.g. .com' 
    )
);

public function beforeSave() {
    Security::setHash('md5');
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['user_password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['user_password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['user_password']);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

#### **app/View/CoreUsers/login.ctp**

```
<h3>Login</h3>

<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('CoreUser');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Please enter your username and password'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('user_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('user_password');
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));?>
</div>
```

#### **Debug output**

All of these are from the CoreUsersController and going in order in which they are processed.

#### Hashed password. This is the same as what is in the DB, when I added the user.

```
'098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6'
```

#### The Auth object

```
object(AuthComponent) {
components => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Session',
    (int) 1 => 'RequestHandler'
)
authenticate => array(
    (int) 0 => 'Form'
)
authorize => false
ajaxLogin => null
flash => array(
    'element' => 'default',
    'key' => 'auth',
    'params' => array()
)
loginAction => array(
    'admin' => false,
    'controller' => 'CoreUsers',
    'action' => 'login'
)
loginRedirect => array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'index'
)
logoutRedirect => array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'display',
    (int) 0 => 'home'
)
authError => 'You are not authorized to access that location.'
allowedActions => array(
    (int) 0 => 'login'
)
request => object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'CoreUsers',
        'action' => 'login',
        'named' => array(),
        'pass' => array()
    )
    data => array(
        'CoreUser' => array(
            'user_name' => 'testy5',
            'user_password' => 'test'
        )
    )
    query => array()
    url => 'CoreUsers/login'
    base => '/cpm_v2_dev'
    webroot => '/cpm_v2_dev/'
    here => '/cpm_v2_dev/CoreUsers/login'
}
response => object(CakeResponse) {

}
settings => array(
    'loginRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'pages',
        'action' => 'index'
    ),
    'logoutRedirect' => array(
        'controller' => 'pages',
        'action' => 'display',
        (int) 0 => 'home'
    ),
    'loginAction' => array(
        'admin' => false,
        'controller' => 'CoreUsers',
        'action' => 'login'
    ),
    'userModel' => 'CoreUser'
)
userModel => 'CoreUser'
  }
```

#### Version of CakePHP

```
'2.1.0'
```

#### Password before login() is called

```
'test'
```

#### Username before login() is called

```
 'testy5'
```

#### Password after login() is called

```
 'test'
```

Here is a quick list of things that I've read in other stackoverflow post that I've tried. Let me know if you need to me to elaborate.

1) I mapped username and password to the fields in the DB. It's where the comments are for fields. I also tried doing it in the beforeFilter() method. Using:

```
$this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'user_password');
```

In the login view the form was created as such:

```
$this->Form->input('username');
$this->Form->input('password');
```

2) I tried hashing the password manually before login like so:

```
 $this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['password'] = Security::hash($this->Auth->request->data['CoreUser']['password'])
   if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
   }
```

#### EDIT0

3) I just tried doing this as recommended by [CakePHP 2.0 Auth Login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014928/cakephp-2-0-auth-login-not-working)

My AuthComponent now looks like this:

```
     public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'CoreUser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'user_name',
                    'password' => 'user_password'
                )
            )
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
        'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'CoreUsers', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);
```

I apologize if I didn't elaborate enough, or I made a mistake. I've been working on this for a couple of days and it has really drained me. I appreciate any help I may receive. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing to solve this issue was following the tutorial exactly as CakePHP has it. I also upgraded to 2.1.2. I was running 2.1.0.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Then I slowly added the configurations I needed. For information about the Auth component I referenced:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Really what my problem was poor troubleshooting. I would make a bunch of changes rather than one at a time. I had my login.ctp view two different ways

```
 $this->Form->input('username');
 $this->Form->input('password');
```

and now it looks like this:

```
 echo $this->Form->input('user_name');
 echo $this->Form->Label('Password');
 echo $this->Form->password('user_password');
```

The second version works.

EDIT0:
This is very important. Without a call to the AppController parent the login will not work.

```
class CoreUsersController extends AppController{
    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');

    public function beforeFilter() {
         parent::beforeFilter();
    }
```

The revision for the Auth component works:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'CoreUser',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'user_name',
                    'password' => 'user_password'
                )
            )
        ),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
        'loginAction' => array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'CoreUsers', 'action' => 'login')
    )
);
```

My salt is still an empty string:

```
Configure::write('Security.salt', '');
```

Setting the md5 hash is only needed in one place. It's not needed in beforeSave() in the model:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    Security::setHash('md5');
    $this->Auth->allow('login','add');  
}
```

beforeSave():

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['user_password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['user_password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['user_password']);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: In stead of manually creating the label in your login form, you can do this: `echo $this->Form->input('User.user_password', array('type' => 'password'));` the 'type' parameter is required in your case because CakePHP doesn't automatically 'guess' that the input should be a password field (which is normally the case if the field is *called* password)

Comment: Also, _"Without a call to the AppController parent the login will not work."_ this should only be required if the 'UserController' does 'something' inside beforeFilter(). If it does 'nothing' then it is not required to call `parent::beforeFilter()`

Answer (score 1):

If you added the user directly in the db, the that's the problem. Even though you have an empty string in the config, it' using that in the salt algorithm rather than not using a salt.  (This is probably a bad idea, but that's another issue).

Also, the Auth->password function is a wrapper for Security::hash() where the salt is always used.  Use Security::hash($password, 'md5', false) instead.  That will no salt the password when you save the user.  However you will probably need to configure your Auth/login function to login without checking for a salt.

I'm positive that your problem is with the way you have configure Auth...the should work fine with your db.

Comment: When I save a new user the MD5 is identical to what is produced by miracle salad md5. So I know the hashing of passwords is correct.  The old system just used md5 and all the current user passwords are stored with just md5 hashes. Once I take this out of development I will have the users create new passwords with the salt. Why there isn't a development schema and a production schema in the DB is another issue, but not a technical one. I really appreciate your quick response. I think you may be right about the configuration of Auth, but what exactly I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I did a copy of a cakephp project and couldn't login on the new one. After weeks of searching for a correct answer I found that all I had to do was to change permissions on tmp folder. For an unknown reason when I copy folders some of them where copied with read only permissions.