# The login() not found there isn't any error in my app with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, postgresql-9.1, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

VERSION CAKEPHP 2.4.5
I'm working with postgresql 9.1

hello i have this problem, that my login don't work I don't know why? There isn't any error, this is my code that I'm using:

UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
     
    //if already logged-in, redirect
    if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));      
    }
     
    // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Bienvenido, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalido nombre de usuario o contraseña'));
        }
    }
```

VIEW
login.ctp

> App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
>
> ```
> <div class="users form">
> <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
> <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
>     <fieldset>
>         <legend><?php echo __('Porfavor ingresa tu nombre de usuario y contraseña'); ?></legend>
>         <?php echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Nombre de Usuario', 'maxLength' => 60));
>         echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Contraseña', 'maxLength' => 60));
>     ?>
>     </fieldset>
> <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login')); ?>
> </div>
> <?php
>  echo $this->Html->link( "Agregar un nuevo usuario",   array('action'=>'add') ); 
> ?>
> ```

model user.php

> ```
>  public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
>     // hash our password
>     if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
>         $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
>     }
>      
>     // if we get a new password, hash it
>     if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update'])) {
>         $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']);
>     }
>  
>     // fallback to our parent
>     return parent::beforeSave($options);
> }
> ```

AppController.php

> class AppController extends Controller {
>
> ```
> public $components = array(
>     'DebugKit.Toolbar',
>     'Session',
>     'Auth' => array(
>         'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
>         'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
>         'authError' => 'Tu tienes que estas logueado para ver la pagina.',
>         'loginError' => 'Invalido nombre de usuario ingresado.'
>
>     ));
> // only allow the login controllers only
> public function beforeFilter() {
>    $this->Auth->allow('login');
> }
> public function isAuthorized($user) {
>     // Here is where we should verify the role and give access based on role   
>     return true;
> } }
> ```

Comment: Are you hashing your password in User::beforeSave()? Try [this section in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords) and this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583002/cakephp-auth-component-not-logging-in/21583392#21583392).

Other things to check:
1. Debug some data to check which `if` statement is being executed?
2. Debug to see if the username and password is being sent.

Comment: thanks but continue without work yet. :'( i will continue trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this the answer
FISRT AND IMPORTANT MY VESION OF CAKE PHP IS 2.4.5

I did read:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords

and I after of this I did a lot debugs and I see that my password is not the same that the pasword of mi Database. but this not that simple because i didn't know, how have the same encriptation, and I didn't know what encryptation I was using, so I look for a lot answer here in stackoverflow and this is the best.
[CakePHP 2.1 Auth->login() not working, but adding user does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234757/cakephp-2-1-auth-login-not-working-but-adding-user-does)

the key to all this is here

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    Security::setHash('sha1');//this is the encryption very important
    $this->Auth->allow('login','add', 'index');
}
```

now this is my code final:

MODEL

User.php

```
 <?php
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name ='User';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'nonEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Un nombre de usuario es requerido',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
            'between' => array( 
                'rule' => array('between', 5, 15), 
                'required' => true, 
                'message' => 'Los nombre de usuario deben contener entre 5 y 15 caracteres'
            ),
             'unique' => array(
                'rule'    => array('isUniqueUsername'),
                'message' => 'Este nombre de usuario esta en uso.'
            ),
            'alphaNumericDashUnderscore' => array(
                'rule'    => array('alphaNumericDashUnderscore'),
                'message' => 'Nombre de usuario solo puede contener letras numeros y barra baja'
            ),
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Una contraseña es requerida'
            ),
            'min_length' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),  
                'message' => 'Contraseña debe contener 6 caracteres'
            )
        ),

        'password_confirm' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Por favor confirme su contraseña'
            ),
             'equaltofield' => array(
                'rule' => array('equaltofield','password'),
                'message' => 'Ambas contraseñas deben ser iguales.'
            )
        ),

         'nombre' => array(
            'nonEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Ingresar un nombre es requerido',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
        ),
        'apellido' => array(
            'nonEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Ingresar un apellido es requerido',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('email', true),    
                'message' => 'Porfavor ingrese un correo electronico'   
            ),
             'unique' => array(
                'rule'    => array('isUniqueEmail'),
                'message' => 'Este correo esta en uso',
            ),
            'between' => array( 
                'rule' => array('between', 6, 60), 
                'message' => 'Nombres usuario debe contener de 6 a 60 caracteres'
            )
        ),
        'tipo_usuario' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('administrador', 'azucar', 'soya', 'avicola')),
                'message' => 'Porfavor ingrese un tipo de usuario valido',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        ),


        'password_update' => array(
            'min_length' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),   
                'message' => 'Contraseña debe tener 6 caracteres',
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'required' => false
            )
        ),
        'password_confirm_update' => array(
             'equaltofield' => array(
                'rule' => array('equaltofield','password_update'),
                'message' => 'Ambos deberian ser iguales.',
                'required' => false,
            )
        )


    );

        /**
     * Before isUniqueUsername
     * @param array $options
     * @return boolean
     */
    function isUniqueUsername($check) {

        $username = $this->find(
            'first',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'User.id',
                    'User.username'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.username' => $check['username']
                )
            )
        );

        if(!empty($username)){
            if($this->data[$this->alias]['id'] == $username['User']['id']){
                return true; 
            }else{
                return false; 
            }
        }else{
            return true; 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Before isUniqueEmail
     * @param array $options
     * @return boolean
     */
    function isUniqueEmail($check) {

        $email = $this->find(
            'first',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'User.id'
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'User.email' => $check['email']
                )
            )
        );

        if(!empty($email)){
            if($this->data[$this->alias]['id'] == $email['User']['id']){
                return true; 
            }else{
                return false; 
            }
        }else{
            return true; 
        }
    }

    public function alphaNumericDashUnderscore($check) {
        // $data array is passed using the form field name as the key
        // have to extract the value to make the function generic
        $value = array_values($check);
        $value = $value[0];

        return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ \-]*$/', $value);
    }

    public function equaltofield($check,$otherfield) 
    { 
        //get name of field 
        $fname = ''; 
        foreach ($check as $key => $value){ 
            $fname = $key; 
            break; 
        } 
        return $this->data[$this->name][$otherfield] === $this->data[$this->name][$fname]; 
    } 

    /**
     * Before Save
     * @param array $options
     * @return boolean
     */
     public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        // hash our password

        if (!$this->id) {
            $passwordHasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data['User']['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data['User']['password']);
        }

        // if we get a new password, hash it
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] =  $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']);
        }

        // fallback to our parent
        //return parent::beforeSave($options);
        return true;
    }

}
?>
```

impotartant

AppController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Application level Controller
 *
 * This file is application-wide controller file. You can put all
 * application-wide controller-related methods here.
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Controller
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * Application Controller
 *
 * Add your application-wide methods in the class below, your controllers
 * will inherit them.
 *
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => 'Tu tienes que estas logueado para ver la pagina.',
            'loginError' => 'Invalido nombre de usuario ingresado.',
            'authorize'=> array('Controller'),
            'authenticate' => array('Form')

        ));
    // only allow the login controllers only
    public function beforeFilter() {

        Security::setHash('sha1');
        $this->Auth->allow('login','add', 'index');
    }
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Here is where we should verify the role and give access based on role   
        return true;
    }
}
```

Important

UsersController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    public $name = 'Users';
    public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'conditions' => array('aprobacion' => '1'),
        'order' => array('User.username' => 'asc' ) 
    );
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    public function login() {

        // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
        debug(Security::hash($this->data['User']['password']));
        debug($this->data);
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            debug($this->Session->check('Auth.User'));
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Bienvenido, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {

                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalido nombre de usuario o contraseña'));
            }
        } 
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 6,
            'order' => array('User.username' => 'asc' )
        );
        $users = $this->paginate('User');
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }


    public function add() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('El usuario fue creado'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Posiblemente el usuario no fue creado. Intente de nuevo'));
            }   
        }
    }

    public function edit($id = null) {

            if (!$id) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Porfavor provea un id de usuario');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }

            $user = $this->User->findById($id);
            if (!$user) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('El id proporcionado no es valido');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
            }

            if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
                $this->User->id = $id;
                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('El usuario fue modificado'));
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $id));
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Disponible solo para actualizar tu usuario.'));
                }
            }

            if (!$this->request->data) {
                $this->request->data = $user;
            }
    }

    public function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Porfavor provea un id de usuario');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('El id proporcionado no es valido');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if ($this->User->saveField('aprobacion', 0)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario borrado'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario no fue borrado'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

    public function activate($id = null) {

        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Porfavor provea un id de usuario');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }

        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('El id proporcionado no es valido');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if ($this->User->saveField('aprobacion', 1)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario re-activado'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Usuario no fue re-activado'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }

}
?>
```

NOw

login.ctp

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo ('Porfavor ingresa tu nombre de usuario y contraseña'); ?></legend>
        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => 'Nombre de Usuario', 'maxLength' => 60));
        echo $this->Form->input('password', array('label' => 'Contraseña', 'maxLength' => 60));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(('Login')); ?>
</div>
<?php
 echo $this->Html->link( "Agregar un nuevo usuario",   array('action'=>'add') ); 
?>
```

just use imagination for edit.ctp, add.ctp

Answer (score 0):

In AppController, add inside `Auth` (after `loginError`):

```
'authenticate' => array('Form')
```

And in your view, you don't need to import `AuthComponent`

Comment: yesterday y prove whith this             'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array( 
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'fields' => array(
                            'username' => 'username',
                            'password' => 'password'
                             ),
               'passwordHasher' => array(
                    'className' => 'Simple',
                    'hashType' => 'sha256'
                        )
                    )
                ),  and not found